# How to install transient package?

Tags: magit

> ...Magit depends on the dash, **transient** and with-editor libraries which are available from Melpa and Melpa-Stable. Install them using M-x package-install RET  RET. Of course you may also install them manually from their repository...

How to install transient package?

What I tried

```
M-x package-refresh-contents
M-x package-install transient <enter>
at this point emacs suggests "transient-" so the transient package is not available.
```

My init.el:

```
; Hide menu bar because I dont use it                                                                                
(menu-bar-mode -1)


;; got this from github.com/solkaz/dot-files                                                                          
;; /blob/7e11b52176685326b5b0c328f557be80cb3d64c2/emacs/dot-emacs.d/init.el                                           
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(package-initialize)
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
```

Comment: When installing magit it should pull dependencies automatically. Sidenote for Emacs 28+: transient has been submitted for inclusion in Emacs and may be bundled with installations in 28.1 or later.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is just to run `M-x list-packages`, find `magit` (use `C-s` to search just like any other buffer). With the cursor on the Magit line, type `i` to mark the package for installation, then `x` to execute. It will install Magit plus all of its dependencies automatically.

Or you could search for transient and mark it for installation if you really wanted to.